# Samba server performance issue

Tags: samba

I recently set up a samba server on a ubuntu desktop to serve a shared directory to another four ubuntu desktops. They are in a Giga-bit LAN. I am getting crappy performance from it and I am feeling neither disk nor network is saturated. I suspect there must be some tuning I can do..

The samba server serves a couple dozen directories with big files ( about 100MB each). Then I have four jobs running on each client machine, reading those files intensively. So 16 jobs total. The jobs should have CPU usage close to 100%. But with this samba setup, their cpu usage is very bursty and in many cases very low. Here is the iostat -x 5 output from the server.

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               5.60     1.20  148.00    0.60 19532.00     7.20   262.98     9.74   65.91   65.71  113.33   6.73 100.00
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.60    0.00    3.20   23.40    0.00   72.80
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               4.40     2.80  165.00    0.60 21676.00    13.60   261.95     9.24   56.11   55.98   92.00   6.04 100.00
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.30    0.00    2.51   24.71    0.00   72.48
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               3.40     1.80  149.40    0.40 19120.00     8.80   255.39     9.22   61.09   60.92  128.00   6.68 100.00
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.30    0.00    2.34   27.67    0.00   69.69
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               3.00     0.00  135.60    0.00 17572.80     0.00   259.19    12.07   86.05   86.05    0.00   7.37 100.00
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.55    0.00    2.81   22.01    0.00   74.64
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00  145.40    0.00 18588.00     0.00   255.68    12.12   85.74   85.74    0.00   6.88 100.08
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.25    0.00    2.79   22.49    0.00   74.46
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00  134.20    0.00 17074.40     0.00   254.46    12.42   92.88   92.88    0.00   7.45 100.00
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.50    0.00    2.77   25.21    0.00   71.51
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               1.20     0.00  141.20    0.00 18042.40     0.00   255.56    12.12   85.68   85.68    0.00   7.08 100.00
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.25    0.00    2.89   22.40    0.00   74.46
```

So the disk read throughput is only less than 20MB/s. I think the disk could achieve at least 50-60MB/s read throughput. How could I debug this further? Could this be a network problem? Or a samba setup problem?

EDIT: I noticed the %util number from iostat is already 100%, and %iowait is more than 20%. So it means the disk is already saturated? but only achieves 20MB/s read throughput? How could I interpret the iostat numbers and optimize my system properly?

Comment: What file system is being served over Samba? Is it ext3/4? Or a separate disk running NTFS? Also what sort of hardware? Sata?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of an expectation issue than an actual issue.  With 16 jobs running concurrently on a what I'm going to assume is a single consumer grade SATA drive in this desktop I'd say 20MB/s is respectable.

Looking at your iostat output you can see that there are about 150ish read IOPs happening and that's about all you'll get out of a 7200 RPM SATA drive.

Comment: In ideal conditions, even. 7200rpm means 120 hard physical IOPS, and you'll only reach higher read operations when the drive's caching is actively helping - not in a majority of cases :) On the average, <100 IOPS is a realistic figure for consumer SATA drives.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. But is there a way to ask samba to read a big block of data every time so that it gets more data back for each IOP? Those jobs will read each file sequentially, is there a way to optimize that?

Comment: Ok, I tried blockdev --setra from default value 256 to a big number like 2048. It seems helping the read throughput a lot. Now the read throughput is much higher than 20MB/s, swining between 30MB/s and 60MB/s.